# Error after upgrading Spyder to 4.0.1 with Anaconda on macOS: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, zsh, spyder

I recently updated my version of Spyder to 4.0.1 with Anaconda on macOS Catalina. I use Zsh and initially the command

```
conda install spyder=4.0.1
```

did not work, so I followed [this guide](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-successfully-install-anaconda-on-a-mac-and-actually-get-it-to-work-53ce18025f97) to get Zsh to recognise the `conda` command, which essentially involved downloading the anaconda command line installer and running

```
bash ~/Downloads/Anaconda3-2019.10-MacOSX-x86_64.sh
export PATH="/Users/myname/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

then running

```
conda install spyder=4.0.1
```

to update Spyder. This seemed to work fine, the new version is stored in `/users/myname/anaconda3/envs/spyder-4.0.1` and upon opening Anaconda-Navigator I was able to specify Spyder 4.0.1, although I had to change the "Applications on" option to "spyder" rather than "base (root)". I could then open Spyder 4.0.1 on the same Python 3.7 projects I had on Spyder 3.3.6, but they could no longer run due to the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

This was not just for `numpy`, it also couldn't find `scipy` or `matplotlib`, although it could find `time` and `sys`. When I run

```
conda list
```

All of the modules are there, and Spyder 3.3.6 still runs fine, but for some reason the new version can't use them.

EDIT: Have resolved the issue. All the modules were had to be manually added to Spyder 4.0.1 in the Anaconda-Navigator window. On the left go to Environments, select spyder-4.0.1 and a list of installed modules appears. In the drop down menu select "Not installed" and select the modules you wish to have installed, then click apply. You can now open Spyder 4.0.1 and import the modules as required.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please see [our guide](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder) on how to solve this kind of problems.

Answer (score 1):

You should update to python 3.7 and then update Spyder.

```
conda install python=3.7 anaconda=custom
```